# how to create a salesforce partner community user in test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, community

I am trying to insert a partner community user in my test class. I have created a contact and associated it to the new user but I'm getting the error : "Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Invalid role assignment.: []"

```
        accList = new list<Account>{
            new Account(Name = 'CourtierPrincipal', Num_ro_ORIAS__c='12345', RecordTypeId = recordTypeMap.get(AP_Constants.rtAccCompte_Tiers_courtier))
        };
        insert accList;

        contactList = new list<Contact>{
            new Contact(LastName = 'CourtierPrincipal', AccountId = accList[0].Id, RecordTypeId = recordTypeMap.get(AP_constants.rtConContact_Business_courtier))
        };
        insert contactList;

        for(UserRole role:[select Id, DeveloperName from UserRole]){
             roleMap.put(role.DeveloperName, role.Id);
        }

        courtierPrincipal = new User(
                                alias = 'testUsr2'
                                ,email='testUser2@noemail.com'
                                ,emailencodingkey='UTF-8'
                                ,lastname='testUser2'
                                ,languagelocalekey='fr'
                                ,localesidkey='fr_FR_EURO'
                                ,profileid = profileMap.get('Principal')
                                ,timezonesidkey='Europe/Paris'
                                ,username=getUserNamePrefix() + 'standarduser2@testorg.com'
                                ,ContactId = contactList[0].Id
                                ,UserRoleId = roleMap.get('PartenaireResponsable')  
        );
        insert courtierPrincipal;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

usually I use the following codes in apex test for portal user. Try to see if it is the same concept :

```
  Account portalAccount = new Account(name = 'portalAccount');//create a portal account first
  insert portalAccount;
  Contact portalContact = new contact(LastName = 'portalContact', AccountId = portalAccount.Id); //create a portal contact
  insert portalContact;
  User u1 = new User( email='genelia.dsouza@gmail.com',
                profileid = portalProfileId, 
                UserName='genelia.dsouza@gmail.com' + system.label.PortalEmailSuffix, 
                Alias = 'GDS',
                TimeZoneSidKey='America/New_York',
                EmailEncodingKey='ISO-8859-1',
                LocaleSidKey='en_US', 
                LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
                ContactId = portalContact.Id,
                PortalRole = 'Manager',
                FirstName = 'Genelia',
                LastName = 'Dsouza');
```

Then make sure the specified role is defined on the user running the test class

Comment: It works.!! thanks a lot.. the role of the user running the test was not specified. And the PortalRole on the community user must be specified instead of specifying the UserRoleId :)